# XML generation error

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I'm trying to generate an XML output with Zend_Framework, but this nasty thing keeps popping up:

```
  XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://cart/index/kurpirkt
Line Number 2, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
^
```

As far as I know there are no white-spaces in any of my include files, and even if there were, I think that the `ob_clean()` function should have taken care of it. Here is my code:

```
public function kurpirktAction()
    {
        ob_clean();
        // XML-related routine
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $xml->appendChild($xml->createElement('foo', 'bar'));
        $output = $xml->saveXML();

        // Both layout and view renderer should be disabled
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();

        // Setting up headers and body
        $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
              ->setBody($output);
    }
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Just noticing that you create a document with version 1.0 but the error you are showing us has version 1.2.

Comment: My bad, was messing around when I posted the error message. I've updated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test, if the additional whitespace occures in all actions of your application.
If so, check
*/public/index.php* and 
*/application/bootstrap.php*
for trailing spaces before `<?php` or old left-over debug statements.

**Edit:** transfered the helpful information from the comments to the answer

Comment: ZF 1.10. And viewing it Via Firefox.

Comment: everything fine with 1.10.6 for me.
have you inspected the contens of the outputbuffer yet?
i suggest to look for some output before ZF starts the output buffering. do other pages (without xml) also have those prepended whitespaces? if so /public/index.php and /application/bootstra.php would be the first ones to look for. typically old debug statements are the root cose of such fragements.

Comment: But shouldn't have the `ob_clean()` taken care of the white-space?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your comments made me look over the whole application again, install xdebug and more. Turns out, that there was a space before my `<?php` tag in the bootstrap file. Removing that fixed the errors. Thanks!

Comment: `ob_clean()` discards only output in the buffer, so every output after `ob_start()`. ob_start is called when bootstrapping the zend_view_resource (i think, not sure). definitly after index.php and bootstrap.php  
nice to be able to help!